# How to embed IronPython in a C# application for game scripting?

Tags: scripting, c#-3.0, ironpython

I'm currently porting a my tiny space game project from Delphi 2007 Win32 to C#(and XNA). In Delphi, i used RemObjects Open Source scripting solution "PascalScript".

Now that i continue developing the game with C#, i'd like to use IronPython for scripting purposes.

The only problem is, that i don't know how to achieve this. I'd be very happy if some of you could give me some advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an even better example ( C# in VS 2008)

**Extending your C# application with IronPython**

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/berniea/archive/2008/12/04/extending-your-c-application-with-ironpython.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see how it can be achieved...

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Call_ironpython__in_C_.aspx) one example to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The DLR in [C# 4.0](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/) will provide native support for calling Python code programmatically; so anything you can try before 2010 will be hackish at best.